# cakephp error linkable behavior

Tags: cakephp

I can't find any good documentation on the linkable behaviour for cakephp.  I'm trying to use it given some code samples I've found on the internet, but I'm getting a SQL Error, as well as it is returning 298 rows which should be 136 due to the fact that it is displaying records without a related record in the table specified in the Rental model.  I figure the code: array('not' => array('Rental.ri_num' => null) would keep those rows from showing.  So, I need to know where there is good documentation on this, and why I'm getting the error listed.  and if I can use this for queries like view all Agents with more than 5 and less than 15 Rentals.  or something like that.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERRORS
----------------------------------------------------------------------------


Warning (512): SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'bind' at line 1 [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 684]

Query: bind 

Notice (8): Undefined index: ReferralCommission [APP\models\behaviors\linkable.php, line 83]

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
CODE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

<?php 
class ReferralCommissionsController extends AppController {
    var $helpers = array ('Html', 'Form', 'Ajax');
    var $name = 'ReferralCommissions';
    var $uses = array('ReferralCommission', 'Referral', 'Rental', 'RentalLineitem', 'Agent');
    var $components = array('RequestHandler'); 


    function unpaid() {
            $this->layout = 'ajax';
            $unpaidcommissions = $this->ReferralCommission->find('all', 
            array(
                'link' =>  array('Rental' => array( 'RentalLineitem')), 
                'conditions' => array( array('not' => array('Rental.ri_num' => null)),
                                       'RentalLineitem.ri_bill_e_dte <' => time(), 
                                      'ReferralCommission.rc_amt_paid' => '0'),
                'contain' => array('Agent', 'Rental')
            )); 

            foreach ($unpaidcommissions as &$unpaidcomm) {
                 $agencyid = $unpaidcomm['ReferralCommission']['r_num'];
            }
        $this->set('unpaidcount', count($unpaidcommissions));
        $this->set('commissions', $unpaidcommissions);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had figured out the reason for this error, and have gotten it several times since then.  Every time I get an error where the query is just "Bind" it has always been the relationships that have caused this.  In this case, both the $belongsTo and $hasMany relationships need to be properly set.  If anyone else gets an error like this, Check both models that are being referenced and make sure the relationships are indeed set up correctly.